# Create Tables in Access with Delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-access

I would like to know how to create a table in Access with Delphi with the values from the user.

Firstly the user selects what month they want to use to insert values for example their income and expenses. Now if the month is not there in which they want to insert these values, the month table ex. "January" must be created in the database.

Now the program should then ask "How many income and expenses do you have altogether" and with this value it should create the amount of fields in this table called for ex. "January". The user should then be abled to set the names of each field what is just created, for ex. "Sales" "Rent".

I know that I need to use a ADOqry. I got this code, but can't figure out how to use it.

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS fakeschema;
USE fakeschema;
CREATE TABLE table1 
    (IDtable1 int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     Line1 varchar(45),
     Line2 varchar(45));
```

Comment: Why is the mysql tag specified on a question about access?

Comment: @TommyA Maybe the short form for *my sql statement* :o)

Comment: @Jano That is not the way to go. The table structure should not follow the data. Instead build a fixed structure that can store all the data.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So what you are saying, is that there is not a way to give the user the ability to actually create their own table in Access and the only possible solution is to create the database with all the tables with the fields pre-created?

Comment: No, it is possible to create tables as you/the user like - but how will you manage this unknown fields in your application? Normal is to have a working context and a data structure for this context the application knows and most important knows how to handle.

Comment: I know that I need to use a ADOqry.  I got this code, but can't figure out how to use it.  CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS fakeschema;   
USE fakeschema;  
CREATE TABLE table1  
(IDtable1 int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
Line1 varchar(45),  
Line2 varchar(45));

Comment: Maybe that should be part of the question..  also, what happens when the year changes?  I think you should work more on your design...

Comment: @Jano Your statement is wrong. You should have an eye on the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ff845663.aspx `USE` is not recognized by MS-Access